# install spatie/laravel-activitylog in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am trying to install "spatie/laravel-activitylog" in Laravel install using command `composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog`

But I am getting the error that says
Don't install Laravel 5.3

But I don't want to update the Laravel version.

I think If I try to install an older version of "spatie/laravel-activitylog". It won't have any compatibility issues with Laravel 5.3.

But I don't know which older version of this package will be best for Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version requires `Laravel 5.5`. That is why you get the error. To use spatie/laravel-activitylog you need to upgrade `Laravel` or download an earlier version.

If you look at the requirements for version 1 here: https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-activitylog/v1/requirements you find that:

> The activitylog package requires PHP 7.0+ and Laravel 5.2 or higher.

This is sufficient with your need so you can install this version by specifying it like this:

`composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog "^1.0"`